# Is the function $f: R \to R$ defined by $y=x^{2}-2x-2$ a surjection?

Tags: functions, quadratics

The problem is to find if the following function is a surjection.

$f: R\to R$ defined by $y=x^{2}-2x-2$

I know that it is not a surjection by looking at a graph of the function but I am new to formal proofs. How would I show that it is not onto (surjection) formally?

Comment: Find a real number that's not in its range?

Comment: I know for example y=-6 is not in the range of the image. My question is more on how to write it more formally then "function can't reach y=-6." I am not sure how to write down the assumptions I am making there.

Comment: Would if help if you write the function as $f(x) = (x-1)^2 - 3$?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is a good first post - you are stating the problem in correct language and you explain your "personal proof". To make progress, look at another example where it is shown that a function is not surjective. Then follow the pattern given there.

Comment: As $x^2-2x-2 = x^2-2x+1-3=(x-1)^2-3\geq -3$ it follows that...

Comment: Identifying a non-element of the range is the first step. Now can you prove that there is no real solution of $x^2-2x-2=-6$?

Comment: Okay so combing @LordSharktheUnknown and MartinR, Something like $x^{2}-2x-2=(x-1)^{2}-3$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb R (x-1)^2-3 \neq -6$ because at best case $(x-1)^{2}=0$. Would this be sufficient?

Comment: $(x-1)^2\ge0$ so $(x-1)^2-3\ge-3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $x\in\mathbb R$\begin{align}f(x)&=x^2-2x-2\\&=x^2-2x+1-3\\&=(x-1)^2-3\\&\geqslant-3.\end{align}So, the range of $f$ is a subset of $[-3,\infty)$ (actually, it's equal to it) and therefore $f$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

f surjective means:
$\forall y \in \mathbb{R},\exists x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x)=y$
meaning that $f(x)=y$ must have solution for any real number y.
Since the range of f is limited to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a value of y outside the range of f and still a real number for which the equation $f(x)=y$ has no solution. Therefore f is not surjective